# Spring MQTT broker

Tags: spring, mqtt, microservices

I want to implement a MQTT broker as a microservice with Spring. I found this documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html

but it does not really help. Who has an idea?

Comment: You want to implement a broker as a micro service? What benefit do you think this will bring?

Comment: The microservice is based on Spring Data REST and behind a reverse proxy called Zuul. Each microservice is registered at the Eureka server, so I  need some kind of wrapper around the broker in order to register it.

Comment: You can't because MQTT works on TCP, while Zuul on HTTP. You must implement Zuul logic for TCP.

Comment: Spring uses Eclipse Paho MQTT Client library, and you can't use it as Broker. Try to use open-source implementations of Mqtt Brokers (eg. https://mosquitto.org/).  Your Spring application probably would run Http Application Server (such as Tomcat) and while you trying using Mqtt instead.